# I am trying to fetch json data from Rest API into react, but it showing some error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the data from Rest API "TVMaze". the data is in json format. I am using react.js for this

this is my `myclass.js` file

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import axios from "axios";

    function Myclass(){
      return(
        axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2019-05-01")
        .then (function(response){
          console.log(response);
        });
      );
    }  

    export default Myclass;
```

This is my `index.js` file:

```
 import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import Myclass from "./myclass.js";

    import "./styles.css";

    function App() {
      return (
        <Myclass/>
      );
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, rootElement);
```

This is the error message that I am getting:

```
    SyntaxError: /src/myclass.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:6)

    src/myclass.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:6) 8 | .then (function(response){ 9 | console.log(response); > 10 | }); | ^ 11 | ); 12 | } 13 | 8 | .then (function(response){ 9 | console.log(response);
> 10 | }); | ^ 11 | ); 12 | } 13 |
    browser
    Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," 8 | .then (function(response){ 9 | console.log(response); > 10 | }); | ^ 11 | ); 12 | } 13 | (null)
    eslint
```

Comment: remove a space between "then" and "(function" **.then(function(response){**

Comment: All you need to do is to remove the semicolon (;) which I'm putting in ** here:

console.log(response);
        })**;**

It will solve this error. How API call should be done in React is another topic. But your error will be fixed by this.

Comment: I tried doing both  , but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. A react component must either return something to display (e.g: dom elements) or `null` but here you return a `Promise` when you write

```
  return(
    axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2019-05-01")
    .then (function(response){ 
      console.log(response);
    });
  );
```

Plus you have a space between `then` and `function` which raises the error.

When you want to show data coming from an API request, it's good practice to call your API from within `componentDidMount` and store your data in the `state` of your component.

You can do it with class-based component:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Myclass extends React.Component{

  state = {data: null};

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2019-05-01")
      .then(function(response){
        this.setState({data: response})
      });
    }

  render(){
    if(!this.state.data){
      return null; //or a loading spinner or whatever 
    }
   return data // here depending on the format of the data (array or object) you might need to do some process.
  }
}  

export default Myclass;
```

Or with hooks:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";


const MyClass = function(){
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2019-05-01")
    .then(function(response){
     setDate(response)
    });
  }, []) // with an empty array as a dependency, the API call will be run only once when the component is mounted.

  if(!data){
    return null;
  }

  return data // same comment than before to show your data properly
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, the first solution worked but then I got the "network error", can you explain me why m I getting such error?? Is It due to axios?? FYI I am trying this code on codesandbox

Comment: No, axios does the work. Can you hit the url directly with your browser ? Mind sharing your codesandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Your myclass component should look as follows.

```
import React ,{useEffect} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

function Myclass(){
 // The below useEffect is equivalent to a componentDidMount.
  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/schedule?country=US&date=2019-05-01")
       .then (function(response){
         console.log(response);
       });
  },[]);

  return(

  );
}  

export default Myclass;
```

Comment: hey,thanks but it still giving me some "network error"

Comment: 2 stack frames were expanded.
createError
https://v3id1.codesandbox.io/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15
XMLHttpRequest.handleError
https://v3id1.codesandbox.io/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:14

Comment: If you have used create-react-app comment out `serviceWorker.unregister();` in index.js